# programatically restart vagrant box after provisioning (Vagrant 1.4+)

Tags: vagrant

I have some fairly complex provisioning on a box, after which I would like to programatically do the equivalent of `vagrant reload`.

The best solution I have seen is [here](https://gist.github.com/scraplesh/7767407), however the code at that link seems to be broken on Vagrant 1.4+ (see the comments below the code).

**Question**: Are there any instructions for Vagrant 1.4?

Comment: related: [Is it possible to restart a machine when provisioning a machine using Vagrant and pickup where the script left off?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34910988/33499)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could give a try to this Vagrant plugin I've written:

https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers

Once installed, you should put in your `Vagrantfile` something like:

```
config.trigger.after :provision, :execute => "vagrant reload"
```

Comment: That does not work for me. Only a message shows that the trigger will be run. But nothing happens actually.